# How to set maxArrayLength in .Net service?

Tags: .net, app-config

in client i do it in app.config :

```
<basicHttpBinding ...
<binding ...
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="50000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

Comment: not clear question this is...please  give full defination and some sample code u use...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean change the reader quotas programatically:
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/09/20/how-to-change-reader-quota-values-programmatically.aspx)